# Create a Bundle card using GDK?

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api, google-gdk

Is there a way to create a Timeline Bundle card using the GDK?

I'm currently creating a Timeline card this way:

```
mLiveCard = mTimelineManager.createLiveCard(LIVE_CARD_ID);
mLiveCard.setViews(views);
mLiveCard.publish(LiveCard.PublishMode.REVEAL);
```

This creates a single Live card in the Timeline. I tried adding another with the same TAG, thinking it would bundle them together and the most recent will be the Bundle Cover card, but it didn't do the trick.

I looked at the docs, and all I could find is how to do it using the Mirror API. 
So is there a way to create a Bundle card using the GDK? Or is this only available through the Mirror API? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need to use Mirror API for this.

You can mimic a bundle using a live card by publishing a `LiveCard` whose action is a pending intent to start an activity containing a `CardScrollView`, which then would contain the cards that you want in the bundle. Tapping the `LiveCard` would then launch that activity and let the user scroll through those cards. You can also go further and attach a menu to the activity so that you can configure menu items for each of the cards, since at that point it's just a regular Android activity and layout.

The tag passed into `createLiveCard` is purely for debugging purposes – it is not used for any other kind of identification or grouping.

Comment: Thanks, I got the scroll view activity to launch with a bunch of cards. Now, I assume this bundle action replaces the Menu action I had previously. So if I want other menu options like Stop, then I have to go back to using a Menu PendingIntent and add a menu option called "View Results", correct? Or is there a better way to combine menu options and the viewing of bundle cards?

Comment: That's correct -- since you only have one action on a live card, you need to choose whether it will present a menu or drill directly down into the bundle. If you need other options (such as Stop), it may be better to make the action launch a menu activity with a view option as you've suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use the Mirror api like described here: https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/timeline